# Given circle that is centered on bottom-left corner of a rect, calculate width of circle's bounding rect so its radius touches the top-right corner

Tags: javascript, css, math, geometry

Given a circle that is centered on the bottom-left corner of any rectangle (square, horizontal, vertical), calculate the **width of the circle's bounding rectangle** so its radius touches the top-right corner of the sizing rectangle in JavaScript.

Considering the image below, I am looking for 1 JS function that can handle all 3 scenarios, given the known width and height of the rectangle.

```js
function getCircleWidth(width: number, height: number): number {
    // return width of circle's bounding rectangle
}
```

**UPDATE:**

See the accepted answer below for the bullet proof logic for this problem, Ended up with the following with help from here https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/diagonal-of-rectangle:

```js
function getCircleWidth(width: number, height: number): number {
    return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2)) * 2);
}
```

[image: Requirements]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of a circle's bounding rectangle, is the circle's diameter (and that bounding *rectangle* is a *square*).

A circle's diameter is the double of its radius.

The diagonal of the given rectangle has a length that is equal to that radius.

The length of the diagonal can be derived from the right triangle it forms with the sides of that rectangle, using the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

So:

```
function getCircleWidth(width: number, height: number): number {
    return (width**2 + height**2)**0.5 * 2;
}
```